# Get value from jQuery in asp.net code nugget?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

How can I get the value from a select field (dropdownlist) into a "code nugget" using jQuery? I have seen this done, but can't find an example of it now.

I have two dropdownlists, and I want to get the selected values from them and concatenate it into an id parameter to send to an action method:

```
$.get('<%= Url.Action("GetTasks","Timesheet", new { id = [Concatenated value here] } %>'
```

How can I get the concatenated selected values from the two dropdownlists with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var url = "<% Url.Action("GetTasks", "Timesheet", new { id = "{0}" }) %>";

var selected = $("#mySelect").val().join(",");
url = url.replace("{0}", selected);

$.get(url);
```